# Exporting / Importing MySQL to/from different character sets

Tags: utf-8, character-encoding, mysql

It's fairly straightforward.

I have a db running tables with DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8; 
The collation is set to utf8_general_ci.

Everything is working fine. The application that uses this database saves anything from mandarine (chinese) to swedish and all is well and fine.

However. The db has the following settings.

```
Variable_name   Value
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

As you can see, for unknown reasons the db has **character_set_database** and **character_set_server** set to *latin1*.

This doesn't cause a problem for the application that runs it, so we're fine there, but whenever we export and import, to a db that has all of the charachter_set_* variables set to utf8 or utf8mb4 (which seems to be the new normal), it makes us having to make an extra SET NAMES query for each session with the database i.e. it's costly and annoying.

Is there any way of fixing this without corrupting the data or disturbing the running application?

What is the appropriate settings for MySQL when it comes to character settings given that you want to run a global app on it and where do I set that so that it sticks, not only to the session but forever (I guess in my.cnf).

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Adding the values from the start of the export.sql-file.
I export using the following line

```
mysqldump --opt --u root -pPassword dbName | gzip > database.sql.gz
```

-- Server version   5.6.21-log

```
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;

/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;

/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;

/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;

/*!40103 SET @OLD_TIME_ZONE=@@TIME_ZONE */;

/*!40103 SET TIME_ZONE='+00:00' */;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0 */;

/*!40014 SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0 */;

/*!40101 SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO' */;

/*!40111 SET @OLD_SQL_NOTES=@@SQL_NOTES, SQL_NOTES=0 */;
--
-- Table structure for table `so_and_so_blabla`
...
```

**EDIT 2**

Adding output from SELECT col, hex(col) FROM table.
Please note that this works fine in both the original db AND in the export, given that I in the db where I imported the data uses SET NAMES latin1 before I issue the query.

```
Europas LÃ¤nder    4575726F706173204CC383C2A46E646572
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the three that `SET NAMES` changes should be worried about.

Chinese has a few characters that need utf8mb4.

Keep in mind that the encoding in the *client* is what `SET NAMES` is talking about.  For Chinese, I recommend

- `SET NAMES utf8mb4` (or equivalent), and
- `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4` on any columns (or defaulting from the table definition) that will hold Chinese, and
- < meta ... utf8 > on web pages -- note, not utf8mb4.

**Edit**

Let's see what steps you used for the export and import.  If mysqldump is involved, look through the file it generates to see if there are any SET commands.

**Edit 2**

Since your `ä` looks like `C383 C2A4` in hex, you have "double encoding".  That probably resulted from

- Having bytes encoded as utf8 (hex `C3A4` for `ä`) to insert into the table, and
- using `SET NAMES latin1` during `INSERT` (probably by default) (bad because it disagrees with the encoding), and
- Declaring the column in the table to be `CHARACTER SET utf8` (good)

What happened is that `C3` and `A4`, being declared to be latin1, were converted to `C383` and `C2A4` to store into the utf8 table column.

When pulling such back out, one decoding will give you `Ã¤` and a second decoding will get back the desired `ä`.

More discussion of "double encoding", plus what to do about it, is found in
[my character set blog](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/charcoll).  There are 4 approaches to fixing the data in the table.  Please experiment with them to see which is best for you.  And use `HEX(col)` to verify what is in the table.

Comment: Thanks for answering. Trying to see exactly what you mean. In your answer, you start with "no". What are you answering "no" to? My main question is how to move the data to a database that allows me to skip the "set names" initial query of "latin1" that I have to do today in order to get things working correctly after an export/import.

Comment: Sorry about the "no"; I removed it.  And asked for more info.

Comment: Added information to the question. Please see everything under **EDIT**  As you can see, it uses SET NAMES utf8 though the server is set to latin1 (though ALL tables are in utf8).

Comment: `/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8 */;` will do the SET NAMES (assuming you are running a version >= 4.1.1).  And the entry in my.cnf is a good idea.  Caution:  If connecting as root, `init_connect` is ignored.

Comment: Still weird to me how I have to use SET NAMES (latin1) for each query to get the values correctly formatted from this db after I import it into a mysql instance that has utf8 as values for all the character_set_* values.

Comment: That could indicate a worse problem.  Please provide `SELECT col, HEX(col) FROM ...` for some cell that is not plain ascii.  With that, I can advise further.

Comment: Thanks much for taking the time. The data is correct, even when exported but the import forces me to use SET NAMES latin1 before every query, or the non-ascii character comes out as above. Looking at them in the db, they look this weird, but in the web client where they are used it comes out as "Europas Länder" which is the correct way it should look.

Comment: Alas -- "double encoding"; see my Edit 2.

Comment: Thank you much for your help. I'll "clean" the data using information about how from your nice blogpost about it. Thanks agin.